# Why is Entscheidungsproblem undecidable not semi-decidable?

Tags: logic, computability

Let's say checking if a proof is valid is decidable. Then surely we can just enumerate the proofs then check if it's valid. This seems to be a semi-decidable procedure. But why Entscheidungsproblem is undecidable then?

Comment: "Undecidable" means "not decidable", not "not semi-decidable". There are many problems which are semi-decidable but not decidable, and the Entscheidungsproblem is one of them.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Oh, then what's the terminology for being "not event semi-decidable"?

Comment: "not semi-decidable"

Comment: @AlexKruckman Is there no word for "not even have an algorithm", no matter if the algorithm halts or not? I used to think that's being "undecidable"

Comment: A semi-decidable problem also called recursively enumerable (r.e.) or computably enumerable (c.e.). So you can say "not r.e." or "not c.e." Why introduce a new word when "not semi-decidable/r.e./c.e." is perfectly clear and concise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot of terminology, and a lot of *redundant* terminology, in computability theory. Briefly, here's the situation:

- **Decidable**, **recursive**, and **computable** are all equivalent.
- **Semidecidable**, **recognizable**, **recursively enumerable** (r.e.), and **computably enumerable** (c.e.) are all equivalent.

In general, the "computation"- and "recursion"-centered terminologies are the standard ones - with the former more modern than the latter. So in the modern literature you'll see references to r.e. or c.e. sets, but rarely to semidecidable sets.

- A set with c.e. (or etc.) *complement* is called **co-r.e.** or **co-c.e.**; I've not seen "co-semidecidable" before, but I wouldn't be surprised if it occurred.
- There is no specific term for non-c.e. (or etc.). You just say "non-c.e."

Answer (score 2):

It is both.
"**Decidable**" means "both semi-decidable and co-semi-decidable". "**Undecidable**" means "not semi-decidable or not co-semi-decidable or neither".
The Entscheidungsproblem is **semi-decidable**: We can enumerate all valid inferences. But it is not **co-semi-decidable**: We can not enumerate all invalid inferences. So it is undecidable but semi-decidable.